# no sound after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio

pulse audio not loading

from dmesg

[ 3215.940984] cht-bsw-rt5645 cht-bsw-rt5645: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> media-cpu-dai mapping ok
[ 3215.941111] cht-bsw-rt5645 cht-bsw-rt5645: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> deepbuffer-cpu-dai mapping ok
[ 3215.941504] cht-bsw-rt5645 cht-bsw-rt5645: rt5645-aif1 <-> ssp2-port mapping ok
[ 3216.004685] input: chtrt5645 Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/808622A8:00/cht-bsw-rt5645/sound/card1/input15

pulseaudio -k
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such file or directory

pulseaudio -D
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.

Alsa Information script:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=66759b8b2dc7d5544c5343fbe642cfb75b8d3663

Comment: I can now run pulse audio, but still have no sound. I  ran sudo sh -c "echo 'blacklist snd_hdmi_lpe_audio' > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-snd-hdmi-lpe-audio.conf" and now have a sound icon. Sound card is built is speaker built-in audio and does not work. It should be card 0: chtrt5645 [chtrt5645]. Apparmor is denying access for snap.pulseaudio. AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio" name="/etc/pulse/daemon.conf" pid=2284 comm="pulseaudio"

Answer (score 0):

So since pulseaudio is loading I decided to load the pulseaudio volume control. I saw that headphones were unplugged. I thought why not, at least I might get some sound. So I plugged them in and they worked and better than that, my speakers started to work.

So I guess it is fixed.